# Xamarin.Forms: How to use DPI and Weights

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms

I developed a lot of apps with Xamarin for Android. Whenever I wanted to show a picture, and wanted this picture to have the same dimensions on every phone, I used weights. They act like percentage values.

So I could declare a picture or a layout to for instance ALWAYS take 50 % of its parent layout.
The result was, that everything look identical on each phone.

Now I switched to Xamarin.Forms to also develop for iOS.

However, I just found out that weights or even DPI (which work kind of similar) do not exist here anymore.

The result is wildly different images sizes between iOS and Android, when shared from the same XAML.

How can I go on about this when neither option (DPI nor weights) is available? Is there an equivalent?

Thank you!

Comment: Just curious, did you downvote and what you don't understand particularly in my answer (which is correct). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are many different solution to solve the UI display issue between iOS and Android .

For example

**Option 1:**

You could use the  **Xamarin.Essentials** package to get the size of screen , then set the percentage of the Image (use data binding).

```
// Get Metrics
var mainDisplayInfo = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo;

// Orientation (Landscape, Portrait, Square, Unknown)
var orientation = mainDisplayInfo.Orientation;

// Rotation (0, 90, 180, 270)
var rotation = mainDisplayInfo.Rotation;

// Width (in pixels)
var width = mainDisplayInfo.Width;

// Height (in pixels)
var height = mainDisplayInfo.Height;

// Screen density
var density = mainDisplayInfo.Density;
```

**Option 2:**

You could binding the size of Image to its parent directly .

```
public class SizeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value / 2.0= 0;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

**in xaml**

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
   <ResourceDictionary>
      <local:SizeConverter x:Key="sizeConvert" />
   </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<StackLayout x:Name="stackLayout" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Image Source="xxx" HeightRequest="{Binding Source={x:Reference stackLayout}, Path=Height,Converter={StaticResource sizeConvert}}" WidthRequest="{Binding Source={x:Reference stackLayout}, Path=Width,Converter={StaticResource sizeConvert}}"  />
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Weights are available in the Grid as part of column or row definitions.